# Set Firebug to automatically display results of a POST or GET ajax request?

Tags: ajax, firefox, firebug, preferences

I would like to set Firebug to automatically display results of a POST or GET ajax request.

Is there such an option to automatically open the response tab? When I am debugging multiple requests it is a bit tedious to click on each one. I've looked through the general options and also done some Google searching.

http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/3279/firebug.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution for me was to just start using [FireLogger](http://firelogger.binaryage.com/) instead. Simpler and cleaner.

Cya later FirePHP!!

[image http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/7227/firelogger4phpmainshot.png](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/7227/firelogger4phpmainshot.png)